# Easier way to keep an hg fork of a readonly SVN repo updated?

Tags: svn, mercurial, bitbucket

I made a fork on Bitbucket from a SourceForge SVN repo with only read access. I would like to keep my fork updated with changes to the main repo but I don't see an easy way to do this. The official Bitbucket documentation didn't offer any solutions.

I know you can setup an SVN repo as a subrepo of a hg repo but this is intended more for managing external dependencies. I would like to be able to pull in the latest changes from the official repo and merge them with my own changes.

I did stumble upon https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SubversionToMercurialHowto which seems to do what I need but it's a bit of a heavy weight process compared to just forking another hg repo and pulling in changes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [hgsubversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion) extension. It allows you to easily make a Mercurial clone of the upstream SVN repository; with that in hand you can manage your changes as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

To work with read-only third-party repository, you will have to follow the workflow outlined in the wiki. Such a workflow is also often called using a "vendor branch" and I once started [another Mercurial vendor branch guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/vendor-branches/) that you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to keep my fork updated with changes to the main repo but I don't see an easy way to do this

Follow-up to Martin

- You have to have local Mercurial repo (in order to  add local changes and pull SF-upstream: BB-repo can't be synced with any other repo directly)
- Local repo **must** be created as clone of SF-SVN repo (you can't add SVN-parent to pre-existing repo) using hgsubversion extension and additional `path` to your Bitbucket repo have to be added into config
- Your workflow with two remotes will be:

  - Pull from SF
  - Merge into branch of your code
  - Edit-edit-edit
  - Commit
  - Push to BitBucket